# ASP - Pikaday - Masterpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Im using the pikaday plugin (https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday). I want to disable all days except Mondays. My current code just block Weekends. As per the doco I should use disableDayFn but I'm unsure of how to use this in my code (below).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#<%=TextBox2.ClientID %>").pikaday({ format: 'DD/MM/YYYY', disableWeekends: true, firstDay: 1 });
        });
    </script> 

     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" </asp:TextBox>
```

others used the below code but I'm not sure how to make it work with my code

```
var picker = new Pikaday({
    disableDayFn: function(date){
        // Disable Monday and Tuesday
        return (date.getDay() === 1 || date.getDay() === 2);
    },
    field: document.getElementById('datepicker') })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example for disabling Monday and Tuesday is correct. To make it your, I suggest you should use the original declaration of Pikaday:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var picker = new Pikaday({
        field: $("#<%=TextBox2.ClientID %>"),
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
        disableWeekends: true,
        firstDay: 1,
        disableDayFn: function(date){
        // Disable Monday and Tuesday
        return (date.getDay() === 1 || date.getDay() === 2);
        }
    });
});
```

If you still want to use Pikaday plugin, like your original code, you can see below:

```
$("#<%=TextBox2.ClientID %>").pikaday({
  format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
  disableWeekends: true,
  firstDay: 1,
  disableDayFn: function(date){
        // Disable Monday and Tuesday
        return (date.getDay() === 1 || date.getDay() === 2);
    }
});
```